# Laravel 4 Custom User Permissions

Tags: php, laravel-4, permissions, eloquent

So I'm new to Laravel and trying to make a permissions system for the users on my application. Here is my approach:

1) Place a column in users table with the name 'permissions'
2) Create a table of permissions with columns id and page-name

Here's how it will work:

- Each page will be assigned an ID. For example, the page **Manage Accounts** has id **1** and the page **Manage Customers** has the id **2** in the permissions table.
- In order to give user full access to Manage Accounts and view only access to Manage Customers, I will make the following entry in the permissions column for the user **1.1111,2.1000**
- Now when the user will land on the Manage Accounts page, I will get the page id for the current page from the permissions table, i.e. **1**. I will then convert the string value from the users.permissions column in the following format: **array('1' => '1111', '2' => '1000');**. Now I can get the user permissions saved against the ID of the page by **$permissions['1'];**.
- I will then have a function to parse the 4 digits and get boolean values for the following in the exact order:

  $canView = true;

  $canAdd = true;

  $canEdit = true;

  $canDelete = true;
- Now inside my page, I can easily put checks and display items accordingly.

**Questions**

1) So first question. Is this a good approach? Or are there better ways for going about this? I like this approach because I only have to add one more table in the database and it will only have as many entries as there are pages on my application, which aren't many. And it also means that I will only have to access the database once and I can then keep on using the values in the variable.

2) Should I create a separate class for permissions? I'm new so I don't completely understand the Eloquent class. But is that something I should be using for this? Or should I just add the functions that I need to create to the users class?

3) Where should I store the values of $canView, $CanEdit etc. Should I place them in the class for permissions and create an object for it? Or should I just use the Users class and access them using Auth::? I do not want to use Session, I don't think it to be safe.

4) Can I somehow have the permissions autoload every time a page is opened? I was looking into beforeFilter, and thinking of creating adding it to the constructor of each controller. Is that a good idea?

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel? take a look to https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: It's more about me learning Laravel. I'm trying to understand how to go about this.